# Append key of JSON as csv column while writing to CSV

Tags: python, json, converters

I am new to Python,
I need to convert the following JSON format to csv.

```
{
"2efbc1d": ["ad5460", 32.8963, -84.3213, 74, 39000, 596, 10048, 8444, "B737", "N958WN", 1395360005, "", "", "", 0, 0, "", 0], 

"2efbaa6": ["a1d0a3", 40.3773, -74.2731, 44, 7100, 249, 8450, 8444, "E170", "N216JQ", 1395360005, "", "", "", 0, 0, "592660", 0],

"2ef8db0": ["a8aa73", 40.8801, -73.4095, 46, 27075, 487, 22372, 8444, "B752", "N658AA", 1395360005, "MIA", "BOS", "AA2412", 0, 0, "AAL2412", 0]
 }
```

its a key:[Array] format.

My code which i modified got and modified from stack overflow writes the Array as csv, but i need to add the key as first column.

My code goes here

```
import json
import csv

with open("data.json") as file:
data = json.load(file)

with open("data.csv", "w") as file:
csv_file = csv.writer(file)
print( data.keys())
newlist = list()
for i in data.keys():
   newlist.append(i)
print(newlist[1])

cnt = 0 #len(newlist)-
for item in data:
    csv_file.writerow(  data[newlist[cnt]])
    cnt = cnt+1
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a list `[key, val0, val1, val2, ...]`. Probably the most straightforward way is:

```
for key, value in data.items():
    l = [key]
    l.extend(values)
    csv_file.writerow(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could transform your JSON as a list of list and then use the `csv` modules' `writerow` as you are already doing. This is what I mean:

```
data = {'2efbc1d': ['ad5460', 32.8963, -84.3213, 74, 39000, 596, 10048, 8444, 'B737', 'N958WN', 1395360005, '', '', '', 0, 0, '', 0], '2ef8db0': ['a8aa73', 40.8801, -73.4095, 46, 27075, 487, 22372, 8444, 'B752', 'N658AA', 1395360005, 'MIA', 'BOS', 'AA2412', 0, 0, 'AAL2412', 0], '2efbaa6': ['a1d0a3', 40.3773, -74.2731, 44, 7100, 249, 8450, 8444, 'E170', 'N216JQ', 1395360005, '', '', '', 0, 0, '592660', 0]}

rows = []
for k, v in data.items():
    new_list = [k]
    new_list.extend(v)
    rows.append(new_list)

print rows
```

This gives you:

```
['2efbc1d', 'ad5460', 32.8963, -84.3213, 74, 39000, 596, 10048, 8444, 'B737', 'N958WN', 1395360005, '', '', '', 0, 0, '', 0]
['2efbaa6', 'a1d0a3', 40.3773, -74.2731, 44, 7100, 249, 8450, 8444, 'E170', 'N216JQ', 1395360005, '', '', '', 0, 0, '592660', 0]
['2ef8db0', 'a8aa73', 40.8801, -73.4095, 46, 27075, 487, 22372, 8444, 'B752', 'N658AA', 1395360005, 'MIA', 'BOS', 'AA2412', 0, 0, 'AAL2412', 0]
```

Now do a `writerow` on each element(sub-list) of `rows`. Or as jonrshrape's answer suggests, write the `new_list` as and when you create it, and do away with the `rows` list of lists.